# Does the `ml2_conf.ini` configuration change required a re-population database in Openstack Ussuri?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

Im new to Openstack administration.

I have a up and running setup of Openstack Ussuri using 1 controller and 1 compute node in lab environment.

By following CentOS related guide I have already setup'ed `self-service` networks option on both compute and controller node.

Now I'll be appending below configuration into `/etc/neutron/plugins/ml2/ml2_conf.ini` file.

```
#Inclusion of `vlan` option in `[ml2]` section
[ml2]
tenant_network_types = vxlan,vlan

# Adding below section
[ml2_type_vlan]
network_vlan_ranges = physnet1:1:4000
```

Complete configuration of `ml2_conf.ini` can be found in here - https://pastebin.com/raw/NpP1NFGi

Does the above change in `ml2_conf.ini` is required a re-run of DB population command as specified in here ?  - https://docs.openstack.org/neutron/ussuri/install/controller-install-rdo.html#finalize-installation

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Whether it requires a reset of the database or not depends on the change you want to make. The problem is, nobody will be willing or able to tell you which settings do require this. I doubt, by the way, that rerunning the population command would be enough. You probably have to delete the Neutron database first.

Comment: @berndbausch, I have updated question with configuration snippet which Im trying to add. Please have a look. Thanks.

Comment: Most probably adding a tenant network type is a change deep enough that it requires recreating the database.

Comment: @berndbausch, If you don't mind, could you please check this https://pastebin.com/raw/NpP1NFGi ml2_conf.ini is valid or not ?

Comment: It doesn't seem to contain errors, but I couldn't say if something is missing (I don't have enough experience writing ML2 configurations).